# git clone localhost?

Tags: ubuntu, gitosis

I am not big into ubuntu, but I managed to set up git on my client and gitosis on the server which I am proud of. I added my local ssh public key to the authorized keys for gitosos and can clone, push, commit etc. Everything works fine, from my local machine to the server - back and forth.

However since the server also serves as my webserver, I simply need to connect to the server and make a "git clone git@localhost:gitproject.git" in one of my webroot folders, but it simply doesn't work.

Do I have to add the server pub key to the authorized hosts? And if so, how? Or is there any other way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have a shell on the server, just do:

```
$ cd /path/to/webroot/directory
$ git clone /path/to/git-repo
```

Comment: This solution works properly, @Mike you shall check the answer as valid!

Answer (score 3):

what is the errormessage?

try running

```
git clone --verbose git@localhost:gitproject.git
```

to get more information