# Git Clone XAMPP on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: git, ubuntu, xampp

I am trying to install butter via Ubuntu 12.04 - https://github.com/mozilla/butter.

I am able to grab all of the files via the instructions on github which copies to my /home/butter directory.  I use XAMPP for my local development.  How can I modify git to download and configure the repositories to run from /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/?

I'm new to git as you can tell but can't find my answer (yet) via researching.  I tried this - [git clone localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888379/git-clone-localhost) but Ubuntu is saying the directory doesn't exist when I do a:
$ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/
$ git clone /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/

Thank you so much for the help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git clone is a command which tells to make a clone of the remote repository to a folder in your current directory where you invoke the command. (The folder name is the same as repo's name unless you specify a different name)

What you need to do is,

goto your xampp htdocs directory (I think this is what you need rather than placing it in the xampp directory)

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

Then clone,

```
git clone https://github.com/mozilla/butter
```

After this you can navigate your browser to hxxp://127.0.0.1/butter and do the stuff you wish to do. (replace 'x with 't')